# Can't in display the pop up window on button click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm developing website in php using codeigniter.I need to add pop window when in click "Book now" button in my view (profile.php) following code  is working perfectly in HTML Page without any problem but when i mix php tags the pop up window come and disperser quickly.this is the code that i using i can't find the problem and heed quick help,Can some one explain the error in here?

this is the code that using

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="buy-btn">BOOK NOW</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="moreInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="moreInfoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="moreInfoLabel"><?php echo $package_data['PackageTitle']; ?></h4>
           </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Number of Peaple :<?php echo $tour_data['Visitors']?></p>
        <p>Itenaries : Elephant Blues, Gallface, Brown Circus, Nelum Tower</p>
        <p>Method of Travel : Taxi Service</p>
        <p>Total Time Estimated : 6 Hours</p>
        <hr>
        <h4>Terms and Conditions</h4>
            <p><?php echo $tour_data['TermsAndConditions']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Book Now</button>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="buy-btn" onclick="$('#moreInfo').modal({show: true});">BOOK NOW</button>
```

Comment: appropriate your help but no change of the result :(

Comment: Do you include the bootstrap.js and jquery.js to your html ?

Comment: Yes i have add some bootstrap and JavaScript.problem is, this code is without any problem work in html

Comment: If you do it correctly, it should be okey. This is my test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yalight/UU6hS/

Comment: I don't what is the reason is. i copy and paste your code,Unfortunately I got same result :( no change

Comment: Maybe you should post how you include the css and js file of bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1v9gxl4lz2oqab/assets.rar this my css and js file of bootstrap and jquery

Comment: <!jQuery-->
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

 <!--Bootstrap-->
 <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Your bootstrap.min.js path is error if I am correct. You should modify it to <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">

Comment: It is same JavaScript files :) nothing change